# How can you parse just the first line of a CSV file?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

How can you parse just the first line of a CSV file?  I want to make sure that all of the appropriate columns are provided in the file, but don't want to process the whole file.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

A better way of doing this is to simply use the built-in [Enumerable](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Enumerable.html) support in [Ruby's Standard Library CSV parser](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html#method-c-open):

```
headers = CSV.open('file.csv', 'r') { |csv| csv.first }
```

The block will result in the file automatically being closed and the call will return an array of the parsed headers.

Comment: Love it!  What do you mean by the built-in Enumerable support?  Is that what allows the .first method?  Why does it need an empty block afterwards?

Comment: @TomRossi Enumerable is a set of methods and behaviors that comes with Ruby. It's what allows things like `each`, `first`, and a host of other goodies. It's native, and it's actually faster than using `for` loops in Ruby because the latter are implemented with the former.

Comment: @TomRossi And I just realized I made a mistake — we're passing the block to `first`, not `open`, so the handle is not actually being closed. I'll update to resolve the issue.

Comment: @TomRossi To explain, `CSV.open` acts very similarly to `File.open` in that if you call the method without a block it will return a file handle. If you call it with a block, however, it will pass the csv object to the block and close the file handle when the block is finished executing, then it'll return the result of the block (which is the parsed headers in our case).

Comment: So in your solution the block opens the file, reads one line, and then closes the file?  In my original solution was it keeping the file open and reading the whole file?

Comment: @TomRossi What you were doing does only read the first line and properly closes the file, it's just a bit roundabout IMO. There's no need to use `File` directly, and what I've done here — again, IMO — is more expressive.

Comment: I guess the shortest way would be `CSV.open('file.csv', 'r').first`

Comment: @YogeshKhater If you read the above you'll see that this leaves a file open. You would need to do `file = CSV.open(...); line = file.first; file.close` instead. Or you can use the block variant where the file is automatically closed for you and is the right way of doing this in Ruby.

Comment: `CSV.open('file.csv', 'r', &:first)` is the short syntax for the above

Comment: As an addition: ``Enumerator#first`` takes an optional parameter. This may help, if you want to compare the first n lines. (Details: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28417601/ruby-enumerablefirst-vs-take)

Answer (score 2):

I figured this out and hope it can help someone else:

```
  # Return true if the headers match on file1 and file2
  def compare_csv_files(file1, file2)
    file1_first_line = CSV.parse File.open(file1) {|f| f.readline}
    file2_first_line = CSV.parse File.open(file2) {|f| f.readline}
    return file1_first_line == file2_first_line
  end
```

Comment: note there is an implicit return value of every method in ruby + you don't really need `readline` here. See my edited answer

Answer (score 0):

Given a file "foo.csv" on your computer:

```
# Return true if the headers match on file1 and file2
def compare_csv_files(file1, file2)
  CSV.parse( File.open(file1).first ) == CSV.parse( File.open(file2).first )
end
```

Comment: By the way, this appears to pass in an open file pointer to `CSV.parse` which is expecting a string, though really just passes it to `CSV.new` unmodified. If you want it to only read the first line from the file you might want to use something other than `File.open`, or if `CSV.parse_line` supports IO, you could use it. But as this is, it appears to be parsing the entire CSV file.

Comment: Just tested it…sure enough, this reads and parses the entire file, and never closes the file pointers.

Comment: ouch, mind if I edit it to take your solution with an enum? (or please proceed with editing it)

Comment: @coreyward How did you figure out the file was never closed?  I thought the block closed the file?

Comment: @TomRossi Passing a block to `File.open` will automatically close it once the block is done executing, but there isn't a block here. I ran the code on a really large file, though there are other ways you could test it (e.g. `CSV.parse(f = File.open); f.closed? #=> false`).