# ruby Enumerable#first vs #take

Tags: ruby

What's the difference between ruby Enumerable/Array `first(n)` and `take(n)`?

I vaguely recall `take` has something to do with lazy evaluation, but I can't figure out how to use it to do that, and can't find anything useful googling or in docs.  "take" is a hard method name to google for.

`first(n)` and `take(n)` are [documented](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Enumerable.html) pretty identically, not too helpful.

```
first → obj or nil
first(n) → an_array
Returns the first element, or the first n elements, of the enumerable. If the   enumerable is empty, the first form returns nil, and the second form returns an empty array.
```

-

```
take(n) → array
Returns first n elements from enum.
```

Telling me "take has something to do with lazy evaluation" isn't enough, I sort of rememeber that already, I need an example of how to use it for such, compared to `first`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, I've looked at the source (Ruby 2.1.5). *Under the hood*, if `first` is provided an argument, it forwards it to `take`. Otherwise, it returns a single value:

```
static VALUE
enum_first(int argc, VALUE *argv, VALUE obj)
{
    NODE *memo;
    rb_check_arity(argc, 0, 1);
    if (argc > 0) {
    return enum_take(obj, argv[0]);
    }
    else {
    memo = NEW_MEMO(Qnil, 0, 0);
    rb_block_call(obj, id_each, 0, 0, first_i, (VALUE)memo);
    return memo->u1.value;
    }
}
```

`take`, on the other hand, **requires an argument** and always returns an array of given size or smaller with the elements taken from the beginning.

```
static VALUE
enum_take(VALUE obj, VALUE n)
{
    NODE *memo;
    VALUE result;
    long len = NUM2LONG(n);

    if (len < 0) {
    rb_raise(rb_eArgError, "attempt to take negative size");
    }

    if (len == 0) return rb_ary_new2(0);
    result = rb_ary_new2(len);
    memo = NEW_MEMO(result, 0, len);
    rb_block_call(obj, id_each, 0, 0, take_i, (VALUE)memo);
    return result;
}
```

So yes, that's a reason why these two are so similar. The only difference seems to be, that `first` can be called without arguments and will output not an array, but a **single value**. `<...>.first(1)`, on the other hand, is equivalent to `<...>.take(1)`. As simple as that.

With lazy collections, however, things are different. `first` in lazy collections is still `enum_first` which is, as seen above, is a shortcut to `enum_take`. `take`, however, is C-coded `lazy_take`:

```
static VALUE
lazy_take(VALUE obj, VALUE n)
{
    long len = NUM2LONG(n);
    VALUE lazy;

    if (len < 0) {
    rb_raise(rb_eArgError, "attempt to take negative size");
    }
    if (len == 0) {
    VALUE len = INT2FIX(0);
    lazy = lazy_to_enum_i(obj, sym_cycle, 1, &len, 0);
    }
    else {
    lazy = rb_block_call(rb_cLazy, id_new, 1, &obj,
                     lazy_take_func, n);
    }
    return lazy_set_method(lazy, rb_ary_new3(1, n), lazy_take_size);
}
```

...that doesn't evaulate immediately, requires a `.force` call for that.

And in fact, it's hinted [in the docs under `lazy`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-lazy), it lists all the lazily implemented methods. The list does contain `take`, but doesn't contain `first`. That said, on lazy sequences `take` stays lazy and `first` doesn't.

Here's an example how these work differently:

```
lz = (1..Float::INFINITY).lazy.map{|i| i }
# An infinite sequence, evaluating it head-on won't do
# Ruby 2.2 also offers `.map(&:itself)`

lz.take(5)                                                                                                                       
#=> #<Enumerator::Lazy: ...>
# Well, `take` is lazy then
# Still, we need values

lz.take(5).force
#=> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
# Why yes, values, finally

lz.first(5)
#=> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
# So `first` is not lazy, it evaluates values immediately
```

Some extra fun can be gained by running in versions prior to 2.2 and using code for 2.2 (`<...>.lazy.map(&:itself)`), because that way the moment you lose laziness will immediately raise a `NoMethodError`.

Comment: Yup, it seems like `take` requiring an argument is the real difference.

Comment: Found using [`pry-doc` gem](https://github.com/pry/pry-doc). To check how that looks in your ruby, install this gem, run `pry` and execute `show-source Enumerable#first`.

Comment: Just looked at `first` of Ruby 2.2. Wow, so different O_O

Comment: So my vague memory that `take` had something to do with lazy evaluation was wrong? They are identical? Hmm.  It doesn't make a lot of sense that they added take as a synonym for first with an argument... but they reallyd did that, and my memory that it's got to do with lazy evaluation was wrong? Weird.

Comment: @jrochkind well, `take` is used with lazy evaulation quite often, because when you inspect a lazy sequence, you only get a cryptic-looking object the lazy sequence is packed in. To get some values from that sequence, you need `take`.

Comment: @jrochkind or maybe I'm wrong, in Ruby 2.2 (and 2.1.5 too) `first(5)` actually gets me 5 first items from a lazy sequence `(1..Float::INFINITY).lazy.map{|i| i}`, `take(5)` doesn't :( I'll come back to this later, I must be missing something.

Comment: thanks for your investigations. it is quite confusing.

Comment: @jrochkind answer updated, I seem to have hit the bottom of this.

Comment: thanks for looking into this, but i still don't understand, like i posted in the original question I had a vague memory that it had something to do with laziness but I don't realy understand what and need an example of how to use first/take with lazy enumeration compared to how the other one woudl work differently.I don't have a very good handle on lazy enumeration in general. The C code isn't helping me.

Comment: @jrochkind ah, so you are unfamiliar with lazy evaluation. Okay, added some Ruby into that boatload of C =)

Comment: Thanks. I guess it's really a different question to look into laziness in general, but why doesn't non-lazy first on an infinite list in `lz.first(5)` wind up crashing things, since it will presumably first try to make an infinite list completely expanded out, before taking the first 5 values?

Comment: @jrochkind `first` merely takes first items from a collection (and returns an array with already evaluated things), so it depends on how it's implemented in the collection itself. We have a lazy collection here, that evaluates items "only as requested". The lazy `take` that this collection has, however, doesn't even touch the collection (!) when called, it just returns an enumerator that should, *when continiously iterated on*, call the underlying collection *no more then the given number of times*. That enumerator and an array both have `each`, so whichever is returned, makes no difference.